# I can no longer see my comments on those particular websites

Tags: facebook

I've made comments on several webpages using Facebook. However, when I log out of my Facebook account, I can no longer see my comments on those particular websites. I assume no one else can either. But when I log back into Facebook, my comments reappear. No one has responded to my comments. This happens on multiple webpages and blogs, so I assume it is not one webpage blocking me. Is there something I need to reset with my privacy settings? Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your comments haven't been validated and approved by the other site.  You can see when you log into the site probably due to the fact that the site knows they those are your comments.  Its likely that once the comments HAVE been approved, they'll be visible to all.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that you can only read comments if you are logged in. The reason most websites do this, is to avoid spammy comments to be indexed by search engines. Since those are not logged in, only the original content is indexed/archived, not the comments.